# How to get many returned tweets from Twitter search API

Tags: python, twitter

I'm looking into the Twitter Search API, and apparently, it has a count parameter that determines "The number of tweets to return per page, up to a maximum of 100." What does "per page" mean, if I'm for example running a python script like this:

```
import twitter #python-twitter package
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key="mykey", 
                consumer_secret="mysecret", 
                access_token_key="myaccess", 
                access_token_secret="myaccesssecret")
results = api.GetSearch(raw_query="q=%23myHashtag&geocode=59.347937,18.072433,5km")
print(len(results))
```

This will only give me 15 tweets in results. I want more, preferably all tweets, if possible. So what should I do? Is there a "next page" option? Can't I just specify the search query in a way that gives me all tweets at once? Or if the number of tweets is too large, some maximum number of tweets?

Comment: Everything you need is here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html. Specifically, you will want to use the `count` and `max_id` parameters. No, you cannot get all tweets unless you pay for the Premium API.

Answer (score 1):

Tweepy has a `Cursor` object that works like this:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#myHashtag&geocode=59.347937,18.072433,5km", lang='en', tweet_mode='extended').items():
    # handle tweets here
```

You can find more info in the [Tweepy Cursor docs](http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/cursor_tutorial.html#introduction).

Answer (score 0):

With [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) you would access pages this way:

```
pager = TwitterPager(api, 
                     'search/tweets', 
                     {'q':'#myHashtag', 'geocode':'59.347937,18.072433,5km'})
for item in pager.get_iterator():
    print(item['text'] if 'text' in item else item)
```

A complete example is here: https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/page_tweets.py